# Even and odd questions in grade table using ExSheets

Tags: tables, exsheets

I would like to create a grade table using the `ExSheets` package. Unfortunately the table is too long for the title page. Having tried other approaches (e.g. longtable-environment, resizebox and others) - none particularly satisfying - I am looking for a way to separate even and odd numbered questions addressed by the `\ForEachQuestion` macro to split the vertical table (see the minimum working example below) into two columns.
Is there a switch to do that or some other way to automatically typeset the table in two columns (each consisting of three "sub-columns")?

Checking the counter for even and odd numbers did not work due to the counter format (`counter-format=se.qu`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
    counter-format=se.qu,
    counter-within=section,
    solution/print=true
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline
\textbf{Question}                           &     \textbf{Points}                   & \textbf{Result}   \\\hline
\ForEachQuestion{%
Question \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{#1}  & \GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}  & {}                \iflastquestion{\\\hline}{\\}%
}
$\mathbf\Sigma$                         & \pointssum                        & {}                \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{First}
\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{1}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}
\begin{question}{3}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\section{Second}

\begin{question}{10}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{10}
Some question
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure question number is not directly available but it is possible to add a property to retrieve it. Then, in order to be able to build the table correctly, it is easier to build the table contents in a macro before actually typesetting the table.

Something like this maybe:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-format = se.qu,
  counter-within = section,
  solution/print = true,
  question/post-hook = \SetQuestionPropertiesX{number=\arabic{question}}
}

% new property:
\DeclareQuestionProperty{number}

% a command that expands the property before saving it:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SetQuestionPropertiesX { +m }
  { \exsheets_set_question_properties:x {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\providecommand*\printgradingtable{}

\begin{document}

% build the table contents:
\ForEachQuestion{%
  \ifodd\GetQuestionProperty{number}{#1}
    \eappto\printgradingtable{%
      Question \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{#1} &
      \GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1} & &
    }
  \else
    \eappto\printgradingtable{%
      Question \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{#1} &
      \GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1} &
      \iflastquestion{\unexpanded{\\\hline}}{\unexpanded{\\}}
    }
  \fi
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcclcc}
  \hline
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Points} & \textbf{Result} &
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Points} & \textbf{Result} \\
  \hline
    \printgradingtable
    $\mathbf\Sigma$ & & & & \pointssum & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{First}
\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{1}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}
\begin{question}{3}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
Some question
\end{question}

\section{Second}

\begin{question}{10}
Some question
\end{question}

\begin{question}{10}
Some question
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The code uses the fact that `exsheets` loads both `xparse` and `etoolbox`.